# RestTemplate POST a Collection

Tags: rest, resttemplate

Ok here iam back to find a solution.

Iam trying Spring RestTemplate `postForEntity` method to send a Collection of instances. When attempting spring gives an error `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.abc.base.domai
n.dto.gift.GiftItemList` Appriciate, if someone can tells me how to send a an ArrayList with spring resttemplate POST method.

RestTemplate bean:

```
 <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
   <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory"/> 
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" /> 
            <bean id="jsonViewResolver" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" >
               <property name="objectMapper">
                    <ref bean="JacksonObjectMapper" />
               </property>              
               <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                          <list>
                            <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                               <constructor-arg value="application" />
                               <constructor-arg value="json" />
                               <constructor-arg value="#{T(java.nio.charset.Charset).forName('UTF-8')}"/>
                             </bean>
                          </list>
                </property>
            </bean>                                             
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="JacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />

 <bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientParams"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="httpClientParams" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams">        
    <property name="connectionManagerClass"  value="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="httpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
</bean>
```

Instance that iam trying to POST,

```
 public class GiftItem implements Entity, Serializable {    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String redeemLocation;  
    private String itemName;    
    private String itemDescription; 
    private String merchantName;    
    private Integer quantity;   
    private Integer imageId;


    public GiftItem() {
        super();        
    }

    //with getters and setters

}
```

GiftItem instance wraaper class

```
    public class GiftItemList implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8202204714984099030L;

    public GiftItemList() {

    }

    private List<GiftItem> giftItemList;

    public List<GiftItem> getGiftItemList() {
        return giftItemList;
    }

    public void setGiftItemList(List<GiftItem> giftItemList) {
        this.giftItemList = giftItemList;
    }
}
```

this is how i use it,

```
public BaseResponse sendGiftEmail(final String token, final User sender,final String message, final GiftItemList giftItemList) {

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    map.add("token", token);        
    map.add("sender", sender);
    map.add("message", message);
    map.add("giftItemList", giftItemList);
    return getRestTemplate().postForEntity(
            "http://localhost:8080/notification/api/notification/send_gift_email",
    map, BaseResponse.class).getBody();
}
```

and the error i am getting,

```
    org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.abc.base.domain.dto.gift.GiftItemList]
   at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write Part(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:310)
   at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write Parts(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:270)
   at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write Multipart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:260)
   at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:200)
   at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:1)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:588)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:436)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:302)
   at com.tapgift.gift.client.impl.GiftClientImpl.sendGiftNotifications(GiftClientImpl.java:101)
```

pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

almost forgot receiver controller,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/notification/send_gift_email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody BaseResponse sendGiftEmail(@RequestParam("token") String token,     @RequestParam("sender")final User sender, @RequestParam("message")final String message,@RequestParam("giftItemList") GiftItemList giftItemList) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add MappingJacksonHttpMessageConveter to your messageCoverter :

```
 List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

You also need to add the dependency for :

```
jackson-core-asl-x.x.x.jar & jaackson.mapper.asl-x.x.x.jar
```

Another thing, you have to make sure that your class have the same attribute as your JSON properties. For example :

```
{"data":{"ticket":"TICKET_870299cf98e227abdbd5f9b7064390c5723a0c6a"}}
```

To fill your class properties, they have to be like this :

person.java

```
public class person {

 private Data data;

 public Data getData() {
 return data;
 }

 public void setData(Data data) {
   this.data = data;
 }
}
```

data.java

```
public class Data {

 private String ticket;

 public String getTicket() {
   return ticket;
 }

 public void setTicket(String ticket) {
   this.ticket = ticket;
 }

}
```

Finaly in your application your add :

```
  person entity = restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestEntity,
    person.class);
```

requestEntity is a String that contains your request body (JSON in my case).

Hope that helped !